# Use a method to return value or assign method result to attribute?

Tags: python, oop

I am currently refactoring some code that made use of globals into a class:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

class test(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.fiscal_cal = pd.read_csv(r'c:\CENSORED')
        self.today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
        self.yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 

    def _calc_period_start(self,input_date,period): 
        month, year, season = map(lambda x: self.fiscal_cal[x][self.fiscal_cal['date']==input_date], ['fmth','fyr','fiscal_season'])
        if period == 'month': 
            return self.fiscal_cal['date'][(self.fiscal_cal['fmth'] == int(month)) & (self.fiscal_cal['fyr'] == int(year))].irow(0)
        return self.fiscal_cal['date'][self.fiscal_cal['fiscal_season'] == season.values[0]].irow(0)

    def _calc_match_date(self,input_date,years_back=1): 
        fwk, fyr, fdt = map(lambda x: self.fiscal_cal[x][self.fiscal_cal['date']==input_date], ['fwk','fyr','fdt'])
        _ = self.fiscal_cal['date'][(self.fiscal_cal['fdt'] == int(fdt)) & (self.fiscal_cal['fyr'] == int(fyr - years_back))]
        return _.item()

    def month_start_ty(self): 
        return self._calc_period_start(self.today,period='month') 

    def season_start_ty(self): 
        return self._calc_period_start(self.today,period = 'season')

    def match_ly(self): 
        _ = self._calc_match_date(self.today,1) 
        return _

    def month_start_ly(self):
        _ = self._calc_match_date(self.today,1)
        return self._calc_period_start(_,period = "month")

    def season_start_ly(self): 
        _ = self._calc_match_date(self.today,1)
        return self._calc_period_start(_,period = 'season')
```

I am confused on where I should be using a method to return information to my program -- or assign the output of the method to a attribute, and then access/use the attribute in

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

class test(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.fiscal_cal = pd.read_csv(r'c:\CENSORED')
        self.today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
        self.yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
        self.month_start_ty = self._calc_period_start(self.today,period='month')
    def _calc_period_start(self,input_date,period): 
        month, year, season = map(lambda x: self.fiscal_cal[x][self.fiscal_cal['date']==input_date], ['fmth','fyr','fiscal_season'])
        if period == 'month': 
            return self.fiscal_cal['date'][(self.fiscal_cal['fmth'] == int(month)) & (self.fiscal_cal['fyr'] == int(year))].irow(0)
        return self.fiscal_cal['date'][self.fiscal_cal['fiscal_season'] == season.values[0]].irow(0)

    def _calc_match_date(self,input_date,years_back=1): 
        fwk, fyr, fdt = map(lambda x: self.fiscal_cal[x][self.fiscal_cal['date']==input_date], ['fwk','fyr','fdt'])
        _ = self.fiscal_cal['date'][(self.fiscal_cal['fdt'] == int(fdt)) & (self.fiscal_cal['fyr'] == int(fyr - years_back))]
        return _.item()
```

These dates are being passed as parameters to other functions that make API calls .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you wondering whether you should be computing attributes in your class when you create an instance or just exposing the methods that do the computation? I think the answer will depend on how often the value is needed (and the cost of the calculation). A middle ground might be to compute the value the first time it is requested, then cache it for use in subsequent requests.

Comment: I am trying to figure out if the convention for returning a computed value should be test.a() or if the computed value should be assigned to an attribute to be called via test.a. If it is idiomatic to assign a computed value to an attribute, what is the pythonic method for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

If the calculated value is conceptually a property of the object you were calculating it for, and you want this object to hold a *state* then you can store it as an attribute. If the class is rather a *service* then it should only return it.

It's often done in a way that one *service* class calculates the values, and the other - *value* class (*POD*) holds the result.

So it depends on the context, and your class name `test` doesn't help with it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- Do you know of any resources for understanding "It's often done in a way that one service class calculates the values, and the other - value class (POD) holds the result."

Comment: @user2726995 *Domain driven design* is the buzz-term. You can easily find plenty information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a bit of a stab in the dark, but I think this might be what you are looking for!

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = x
```

If you write your code like this you can do things like this

```
c = C()
print c.x
c.x = 3
```

But of course you can do more complicated things than just update a variable!

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):